# Using virtualenv cross-platform (Linux and Windows) in Pycharm

Tags: python, flask, apache2, virtualenv, pycharm

I've created a virtualenv for my project on Linux and installed the packages I need just fine. When setting up my project in Pycharm, I can select the interpreter to use from venv/bin and Pycharm picks up all the packages in that virtualenv.

I also like to develop on a Windows machine, and I'd like to be able to use the same virtualenv I created on Linux when I clone it from git. However the interpreter created by Linux is a script that runs `python3`; this means I'd have to create a new Windows style virtualenv.

So my question is, is there a way I can create a venv that can be used cross platform?

Comment: What you *actually* want, I suspect, is to install the *same packages* in a virtualenv on Windows. Google `requirements.txt`. You don't want to version the environment itself, just what's installed in it.

Comment: Yeah i was trying to avoid going down this route, but i guess ill have to. Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

A virtualenv is specific to the platform and location it was created on.  You should not check it into version control.  Each environment you develop in will have its own virtualenv. You make your package installable with [`setup.py`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/#configuring-your-project), and/or specify requirements in [`requirements.txt`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing/#requirements-files) in order to recreate the virtualenv.